# ListFragment always uses match_parent/fill_parent

Tags: android, android-fragments

Does anyone have a solution on ListFragment always forcing itself to behave with match_parent instead of wrap_content, i  placed it on LinearLayout with wrap_content and used something like

```
getView().setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,70));
```

on the ListFragment and even set forced width on the row xml but it still uses match_parent.
Also it seems that even if i use fragment on xml or add the listfragment dynamically it still forces itself to match_parent.

Any help would be awesome. thanks

Comment: I am also having this problem. Tried all kinds of layouts, weights, etc--the list still fills the whole screen and does weird overlapping things with the other Views in the layout. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have definite sizes for the width and height of a ListView, or you can have `match_parent`. `wrap_content` doesn't really make any sense for a `ListView` especially as the types of items in a list can change - so a list might be 200 pixels wide if that was the width of the widest visible item, but then if you scrolled down the widest item might be 300 pixels wide which would cause the width of the ListView to change.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I was having a similar problem. I managed to fix my issue; maybe it'll help you as well.

In my Activity, I was creating the Fragment like this:

```
DepartmentsFragment dFragment = new DepartmentsFragment();
dFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
dFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
        android.R.id.content, dFragment).commit();
```

I changed the fourth line to this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
        R.id.list, dFragment).commit();
```

to reflect the id of the View I wanted my Fragment to replace, and it started working as desired. `android.R.id.content` was telling it to fit the whole screen.

Hope this helps!